# WPF pass parameters to style for internal converter

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

Let's say I have this style :

```
        <bindingConverter:EnumToGridRowVisibilityMultipleConverter x:Key="EnumToGridRowVisibilityMultipleConverter"></bindingConverter:EnumToGridRowVisibilityMultipleConverter>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type RowDefinition}" x:Key="ModelBoundHeight">
            <Setter Property="Height">
                <Setter.Value>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{bindingConverter:EnumToGridRowVisibilityMultipleConverter}">
                            <Binding Path="TerminalConfiguration.ConnectionSoftware"></Binding>
                            <MultiBinding.ConverterParameter>
                                <x:Array Type="{x:Type local:EnumConnectionSoftware}">
                                    <x:Static Member="local:EnumConnectionSoftware.foo"></x:Static>
                                    <x:Static Member="local:EnumConnectionSoftware.bar"></x:Static>
                                </x:Array>
                            </MultiBinding.ConverterParameter>
                        </MultiBinding>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Now I want to use it into my xaml so I call it like this :

```
   <RowDefinition Name="MyRow" Style="{StaticResource ModelBoundHeight}" />
```

My Converter :

```
 [ValueConversion(typeof(bool), typeof(GridLength))]
public class EnumToGridRowVisibilityMultipleConverter : MarkupExtension, IMultiValueConverter
{
    private int Height = 30;
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        //Convert parameter to an array of string
        var strings = ((IEnumerable)parameter).Cast<object>()
            .Select(x => x == null ? x : x.ToString())
            .ToArray();

        return strings.Contains(values[0].ToString())? new GridLength(Height, GridUnitType.Pixel) : new GridLength(0);
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return this;
    }
}
```

I want to set the property Height for my converter. I want it to be set dynamically in the xaml.
But I need to pass it to the style, so the style pass it to the converter. How Can I do that ?

Is there a way to pass an argument to the style so we can then pass it to the converter into the style ?

Comment: Did you consider the `ItemContainerStyleSelector` approach ? I believe this is a better tool for what you are trying to do.

Comment: You are already setting the `Height` property in your `Style`, aren't you? Or where do you want to specify the `Height`?

Comment: I want to pass the height into this line :
 <RowDefinition Name="MyRow" Style="{StaticResource ModelBoundHeight}" />
So it may set the Height property into the converter